# Calling an external service from within Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a service (/deployment/pod) running in my Minikube (installed on my Mac) that needs to call an external http service that runs directly on my Mac (i.e. outside Minikube). The domain name of that external service is defined into my Mac /etc/hosts file. Yet, my service within Minikube cannot call that external service. Any idea what I need to configure where? Many thanks. C

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your prompt answer.
The solution that consists in changing the /etc/hosts file would not work. The other solution (creating an endpoint and a corresponding service) worked well. Thanks again - I have really been struggling with that.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct so that other can understand easily. It will also help others.

Answer (score 6):

Create `Endpoints` that will forward traffic to your desire external IP address (your local machine). You can directly connect using `Endpoints` but according to `Goole Cloud best practice` ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services)) is to access it through a `Service`

[image]

Create your `Endpoints`

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: local-ip
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 10.240.0.4  # IP of your desire end point
   ports:
     - port: 27017     # Port that you want to access
```

Then create you `Service`

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: local-ip
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 27017
   targetPort: 27017
```

Now you can call external http service using the `Service` name. In this case `local-ip` like any other internal service of `minikube`.

Comment: Hi, I followed these steps.However , I am still not able to hit my external system.Another issue is-> My external system VIP has '.' in its name and while apply the yaml, its giving error.Please help out

Comment: I am getting java.net.UnknownHostException while hitting the external service.

Comment: can you give an example of you VIP with `.`?

Answer (score 0):

Because your minikube is running on a virtual machine on your laptop , you just need `minikube ssh` into that machine and enter the address of your external service into the `/etc/hosts` file of that virtual machine.