# How to connect to a private IP from Kubernetes Pod

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I am trying to connect to a private IP from within a pod. Ping to that IP from the pod returns unreachable. However, I am able to ping that IP from the host system. What is the best way to route the traffic from the pod to the destination private IP?

Comment: Is that another pod / service you are trying to reach?

Comment: Do you have IP forwarding turned on at the Kubernetes host level? This is a kernel option that is often disabled by default.

Comment: @cookiedough it is another service.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same solution as the answer below, look at [internal dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) in the link, you can refer to other pods and services through something like: `foo.bar.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pods are not allowed to connect directly outside of kubernetes network. You can find more details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/). To connect external IP you have to define `Endpoints` and Kubernetes will redirect request from inside pod to that IP. If you private IP need any extra task like DNS configure or anything else will is out of kubernetes. For kubernetes you will need to define `Endpoints`. Create you `Endpoints`

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: local-ip
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 10.240.0.4  # IP of your desire end point
   ports:
     - port: 27017     # Port that you want to access
```

Now you can connect from inside you pods using `Endpoints` name. But better to access `Endpoints` through `Service`. You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services).
You can find similar answer and flow diagram [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464722/calling-an-external-service-from-within-minikube/54465759#54465759).

Comment: I will try this and let you know

Comment: Hello am new to Kubernetes and am a bit held at this point, So I have created this endpoint how do I reference it in my code using typescript. mongodb://${config.mongourl}:${config.mongoport}/${config.collection}?authSource=admin`;