# Access corporate resources from Minikube

Tags: networking, kubernetes, vpn, minikube

I am using a VPN connection to access corporate resources from my Laptop. However, I am unable to access these resources from the VM created by Minikube.

I want to be able to do exactly [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) but the address of the external resource is unreachable from the cluster.

Any ideas how I can do this with Minikube?

Comment: I am investigating your issue. In a meantime could you please check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912179/minikube-services-access-local-vpn) solves your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to access the corporate network from the VM by [downloading the latest version of virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and using that as the `--vm-driver` for minikube while connected to the VPN on my laptop. (Was using hyperkit before)

```
minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have correctly defined `endpoints` and `services`. That way Kubernetes will redirect requests from inside the pod to the desired outside IP. It is well described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465759/11560878) which I am posting as a community wiki here:

> Create `Endpoints` that will forward traffic to your desire external
>   IP address (your local machine). You can directly connect using
>   `Endpoints` but according to `Google Cloud best practice` ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services)) is
>   to access it through a `Service`
>
> [image]
>
> Create your `Endpoints`
>
> ```
> kind: Endpoints
> apiVersion: v1
> metadata:
>  name: local-ip
> subsets:
>  - addresses:
>      - ip: 10.240.0.4  # IP of your desire end point
>    ports:
>      - port: 27017     # Port that you want to access Then create you `Service`
>
> kind: Service
> apiVersion: v1
> metadata:
>  name: local-ip
> Spec:
>  type: ClusterIP
>  ports:
>  - port: 27017
>    targetPort: 27017
> ```
>
> Now you can call external http service using the `Service` name. In
>   this case `loal-ip` like any other internal service of `minikube`.

Please let me know if that helped.