# How to reach kafka from within container on minikube?

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, minikube, kafka-python

I'm setting up a python app, and I would like to produce a message for kafka.
The kafka server is running locally on my computer (not in minikube) and the `app.py` runs in a container in minikube.

The code of `app.py` is this:

```py
try:
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['addr:9092'])
    producer.send('flask.logs', json.dumps("HELLO").encode('utf-8'))
    producer.flush()
    print(f"[P-KAFKA] kafka log posted")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"[P-KAFKA] kafka bad posted")
    raise e
```

I tried to do few things like:

1. with `localhost` in place of `addr`, I bridged port 9092 of localhost with port 9092 of minikube but this solution doesn't work.
2. with `192.168.1.3` (my PC computer's IP) in place of `addr` it still doesn't work.

I don't know what to do.

--SOLUTION--
i used ngrok, basically ngrok forwards traffic from your local port, that you can choose, in a public adress.
very cool.
otherwise this is almost the same question : 
[Calling an external service from within Minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464722/calling-an-external-service-from-within-minikube)

Comment: I would recommend doing an Internet search for phrases like "access localhost from minikube" or "kafka localhost minikube", there are several possible solutions that could work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external service from within Minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464722/calling-an-external-service-from-within-minikube)

Comment: yes is almost the same !

Comment: You can post the solution as an answer and provide more details, maybe it will be helpful for more people.

Comment: i just modified the answer with the solution ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The kafka server is running locally on my computer (not in minikube) and the app.py runs in a container in minikube.

Then you don't need ngrok.

Minikube routes request to the host machine. Your host machine contains a running broker. There's never a need for an external service, **especially** not routing over the internet.

You simply need to use your host IP or DNS name in your Python code, preferably via an environment variable, say `KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP`.

And you need to add the same address to your `server.properties` as an `advertised.listeners` address

Answer (score -1):

For this we can use [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

There is a pretty nice blog post explaining how to [Expose Kubernetes services over HTTPS with Ngrok](https://stefanprodan.com/2018/expose-kubernetes-services-over-http-with-ngrok/)

> Have you ever wanted to expose a Kubernetes service running on Minikube on the internet and have a temporary HTTPS address for it? If so then Ngrok is a great fit to do that without any firewall, NAT or DNS configurations. If you are developing an application that works with webhooks or oauth callbacks Ngrok can create a tunnel between your Kubernetes service and their cloud platform and provide you with a unique HTTPS URL that you can use to test and debug your service.

There is also article on medium [Expose Kubernetes services with ngrok](https://medium.com/@abhishek1987/expose-kubernetes-services-with-ngrok-65280142dab4).

> Very often, there is a need to expose Kubernetes apps running in  `[minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/)`to the public internet. This post just provides a manual, yet quick and dirty hack for this using  `[**ngrok**](https://ngrok.com/)`  (it’s probably been done before, but here it goes anyway)
>
> We’ll use a simple  `[nginx](https://www.nginx.com/)`  app to test things out i.e. we’ll expose an nginx server (running as a single replica  [Kubernetes Deployment](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/application/deployment.yaml)) as a publicly accessible URL.

Comment: As I commented on the other answer, you should not expose Kafka to the open internet without access controls. You only need an ingress service, not ngrok