# cannot access external ip in minikube with EndpointSlice and Service

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-service

Following the example on [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) I'm trying to connect to an external IP from within the cluster (and i need some port proxy, so not ExternalName service). However it is not working. This is the response I'm expecting

```bash
ubuntu:/opt$ curl http://216.58.208.110:80
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

if I use the following config

```yaml
apiVersion: discovery.k8s.io/v1
kind: EndpointSlice
metadata:
  name: my-service-1
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/service-name: my-service
addressType: IPv4
ports:
  - name: http
    appProtocol: http
    protocol: TCP 
    port: 80
endpoints:
  - addresses:
      - "216.58.208.110"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP 
      port: 8888
      targetPort: 80
```

I expect the following command to get same result:

```bash
minikube kubectl -- run -it --rm --restart=Never curl --image=curlimages/curl curl -- my-service:8888
```

but I get nothing.
if I start an debian image with

```bash
minikube kubectl -- run -it --rm --restart=Never debian --image=debian:latest
```

then

```bash
apt update && apt install dnsutils curl -y && nslookup my-service && curl my-service:8888
```

gives

```bash
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   my-service.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.111.116.160
curl: (28) Failed to connect to my-service port 8888: Connection timed out
```

Am i missing something? or is it not supposed to work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error it seem that if `ports[0].name = http` is set for the `endpointslice` it stops working.

it stops working for when for the `service` `spec.ports[0].targetPort` is set to `80` or `http` as well.

(it does work when `ports[0].name = ''`)

Further investing shows that it works if:

for `service`

```yaml
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    name: http
    targetPort: http
```

for `endpointslice`

```yaml
ports:
  - port: 80
    name: http
```

I guess if you want to name them both the `service` and the `endpointslice` have to have corresponding `.name` values.

Answer (score 0):

As per the first curl response  i can see 301 Moved  error which is used for permanent URL redirection.Current links using the URL that the response is received for should be updated. try to use https:// in your link.

The cURL error 28: Operation timed out error indicates that the server was unable to download the
. zip file containing the new files before it reached your server's connection timeout limit.

Refer to this [Doc](https://help.whmcs.com/m/updating/l/1566863-troubleshooting-a-curl-error-28-operation-timed-out-error) for more information.

Comment: I understand the HTTP error, the problem is that I should receive the same HTTP error though the use of the EndpointSlice and Service as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465759/12528320)